# How to obtain userId specified by Alexa user during account linking

Tags: security, spring-security, amazon-iam, alexa-skills-kit

During account linking process, Alexa user is redirected and presented with a form to enter his credentials (ID and/or password).  Based on what's provided, the user is then being validated by the authentication flow, upon which success an `accessToken` is embedded in Alexa request and the user is redirected to the OAuth resource.

Is there a way to pass the ID of the user obtained in the above interaction as part of the Alexa request (JSON `session\user\userId`), **instead of** (or in addition to) it being a userId that gets generated during user's enabling their skill on a device?  Or can the userId be gleaned from the `accessToken` generated after linking user's account?

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the userId specified by your OAuth provider? There should be an API to retrieve the userId based on the `accessToken`. Using Login with Amazon for example, when you [verify the access token](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/implicit-grant.html#verify-access-tokens), it would return `user_id` as part of the response.

If you're referring to getting the user's email (that's the "ID" to login to an Amazon account), you would need to add the relevant scope (e.g. [`profile`](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/customer-profile.html) for LWA) based on your OAuth provider in order to retrieve that from an `accessToken`.

Comment: Do you happen to know the answer to this related question? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75967998/how-can-users-grant-permission-for-my-website-to-manage-their-amazon-alexa-lists